# Inverting color of textview on SlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, android-animation, android-tabhost

I need to create animation that is due this briefly invert the color of the TextView while he does the animation. I'm using SlidingTabLayout together with ViewPager, like this:

[image]

The colors is only for reference.

The complete code is here:

SlidingTabLayout: [here](http://pastebin.com/sg7uQ5ix)
SlidingTabStrip: [here](http://pastebin.com/dKmYZqMY)

**[UPDATE]**

I've tried it:

```
    int normalTextColor = Color.argb( 0, 0, 0, 0);
    int pressedFilterColor = Color.argb(225, 238, 11, 83);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); //make a 1-pixel Bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    canvas.drawColor(normalTextColor); //color we want to apply filter to
    canvas.drawColor(pressedFilterColor, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN); //apply filter

    int pressedTextColor = bitmap.getPixel(0,  0);
    textView.setTextColor(pressedTextColor);
```

But still not working.

Comment: Shouldn't the MAPA on the first image be black?

Comment: Yes, but ins't the focus of the question. It's another problem, can you help me?

Comment: I don't think there's any simple way of doing this on Android :/

Comment: I've think: create a black draw where is gray and tint the text. Will be hard. The Stack Exchange Android app change the color strongly.

Answer (score 1):

As Raybaybay said it is no simple way to this in Android. You are going to have to work with layers. If you are familiar with Photoshop or Gimp, you how what layers are, if not take look here http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-combining.html#gimp-concepts-layers. The key here is to know how to combine the layers. Start by testing the screen and multiply modes http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html. The Javadoc on PorterDuff Modes is useless, but this article (jump straight to the "transfer" section) should help you http://www.xenomachina.com/2011/05/androids-2d-canvas-rendering-pipeline.html understand what is going on.

Now, from you code I see you are familiar with the Android Samples. You should check the Graphics/Xfermodes demo, on the "APIDemos" sample. You can install it directly from Eclipse: new > other > Android Sample Project. The demo shows which PorterDuff Modes there are and how to use them. I hope this helps.

Comment: I am very grateful for your comment. I will study this method of PorterDuff you explained. Thank you.

Comment: You need to draw two bitmaps on the canvas.  Something along these lines `canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, ..., paint); paint.setXfermode(mode); canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, ..., paint); paint.setXfermode(null);`